# How do you integrate HTML with Django?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have an HTML file that has a web page design with a single form, for a user to enter his name. I want to create an six entry array for every submission (to later be filled with information on another page)

Is Django the proper utility to use for this? I would like to have the html design file and the python back end processing as separate files. If so, can anyone point me towards a good place to read about integrating HTML and underlying python codes that process HTML submission forms?

Comment: Django isn't really a "utility" in the sense that you put it between an HTML page and a Python script to tie them together in ten minutes time.

Comment: I wasn't sure what to call it. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Django may be overkill for this. If all you want is a way to link a form to some backend Python code, a micro framework like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) might be a better choice.

Here is how you do a simple form with Flask:

Create a directory `project` and inside it, a directory `templates`

Your template is simple:

```
{% if name %}
    Hello {{ name }}
{% endif %}
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" value="Enter your name">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Save that as `index.html` in the `templates` subdirectory.

Create a file called `go.py` in the `project` directory, and in it copy and paste this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])
def process_form():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form_input = request.form['name']
       return render_template('index.html',name=form_input)
    else:
       return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

Finally from the `project` directory, type:

`python go.py`

Open your browser and go to `http://localhost:5000/`

Answer (score 2):

You can create [html form](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07/) in Django, though you may have to convert the form to a [template](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04/).

In case this you first time to use django, you may go though the [official](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/) Django book

Comment: Just to keep current, the official Django book is quite out of date and first time Django users should start with the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/)

Answer (score 1):

Django provides a template system (in which the presentation files are separate from the business logic and the entire system is highly decoupled). The template language is simple (but very powerful) text substitution on top of an existing text file. You can use the Django templates in HTML (full or partial), text, XML, JSON, or nearly any other text-based format.

Django also allows you to hook into another template system, but I don't know a lot about how that works.

Look at the [Django template documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/) for more information.